# How can I keep content from re-sizing it's wrapper div?

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm a css noob, and though I want this DIV to resize when the window is resized, I don't want inner content to change the size of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, all were good so I went with the guy with the least rep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overflow statement. e.g.

overflow: hidden; /* all content hidden as it spills over */

overflow: auto; /* Scroll bars appear on div when required to allow moving around */

overflow: scroll; /* Scroll bars will be present at all times */

Comment: //why you ask? IE6 will ignore any commented declarations! // display:totally-messed-up

Comment: Oops sorry about the //, was on a c# thing at the time

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Answer (score 0):

set `overflow: hidden` on the containing div

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into CSS and the `overflow` directive?  You can use this to tell the div to scroll or truncate/hide its content when the content is too large.